# Error in nullable property foreign key constraints

Tags: c#

I am getting the following error which I am trying to solve in the past couple of hours. Can someone help me resolve it.

I want to make the property `Table2Id` in `Table1` nullable, so I can pass `null` values.

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Table1_Table2_Table2Id". The conflict occurred in database "Db", table "dbo.Table2", column 'Id'. The statement has been terminated.

```
public  class Table1 : Entity
{
     ...
     public int Table2Id { get; set; }
     ...

     public virtual  Table2 Tables2 { get; set; }
}

public  class Table2 : Entity
{
     ...
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     ...

     public ICollection<Table1> Tables1 { get; set; }
}
```

**Table1EntityConfiguration**

```
builder.HasOne(c => c.Tables2)
       .WithMany(c => c.Tables1)
       .HasForeignKey(cc => cc.Table2Id )
       .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
       .IsRequired(false);
```

Comment: so you want `public int? Table2Id {get; set;}`?

Comment: @Progman I read in SO that ? will make it nullable, therefore, i added it. But nothing changed.

Comment: Is the `Table2Id` column in the `Table1` database table nullable as well?

Comment: Yes. I want it Nullable.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your classes:

```
public  class Table1: Entity
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name{ get; set; }
   ...
   public int? Table2Id { get; set; }
   ...

   public virtual  Table2 Table2{ get; set; 
}

public  class Table2: Entity
{
   ...
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name{ get; set; }
   ...

    public ICollection<Table1> Tables1 { get; set; }
}
```

this is your db context. But if you use net5 you don't need it at  all:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Table1>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasOne(d => d.Table2)
                   .WithMany(p => p.Tables1)
                   .HasForeignKey(d => d.Table2Id)
                   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
                 
            });
```

Comment: WHat does `ClientSetNull` do ?

Comment: ON DELETE NO ACTION , the same as restrict